# What are the 'from' and 'to' dimensions of transition_params in tf.contrib.crf.crf_log_likelihood?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

On TensorFlow, I want to pass a transition_params matrix as argument to `tf.contrib.crf.crf_log_likelihood` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/crf/crf_log_likelihood), in order to initialize the transitions matrix of the CRF. Although, in the documentation, it is not clear which dimension of this matrix corresponds to the first tag of the transition and which dimension corresponds to the second.

So, let `T` be the transitions matrix, does `T[i,j]` represent the score of the transition from tag `i` to tag `j`, or is it the other way around?